# Public properties from another class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dll, class-library

I've tried searching... a lot for the answer, but as I'm not too sure what exactly I'm trying to do I can't seem to find anything.

I'm trying to write a dll in order to handle errors thrown from a vb.net app. In the dll I need several forms (I'm not totally sure if they can have forms - I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to dll's) for which the user can type in their message about the error and submit it.

I need to be able to pass strings to the form and for the form to be able to access public subs in the class file.

For instance I have a public sub called Emailer, which I want, when the submit button is clicked from the form to be run.

Or, lets say I have a public string:
    `Public strName as string = nothing`
why cant I, from the class file just do this:
    `frmFormName.strName = "abc"`

Not sure if I've explained that very well, but like I said I'm a bit of a newbie with this stuff.

Comment: .Dll files (Dynamic Link Libraries) do not have a user interface.  If you want to have forms then you need a Windows Form Application (.exe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can have froms in a DLL it just does not have a entry point you will need a exe for this this. Which it sounds like you have

2) You will need to add a [project reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx) to a dll from your exe

ok not sure how this will work but try to download this [Example project](http://www.tempfiles.net/download/201203/234699/MyForms.html) let me know if you have more questions

Comment: Ok, Great, so how would I use the form from the class file? intellisense shows limited options for the form. In the class file I have `dim myForm as new frmFormName` which then allows the controls on the form to be used within the class file, but in the form, I cant use anything from the class... its doing my head in, I cant seen to find any answers anywhere. Thanks for the info so far.

Comment: Then make a instance

dim f as new MyDLL.myform()

Comment: Thats what I have done in the class, to access the controls on the form. So you're saying, I can just access everything in the class by doing the same `dim myClass as new dllname.dllclass`? which is all in the same project?

Comment: You also might need to make your form public instead of private

Comment: So, I'm still totally lost, I can use controls from the form in the Class file (`Dim MyForm As New frmMainView`), But I have a sub called `Public Sub Emailer()` which is in the class file but I can't seem to figure out how to use anything on the class file in the form. I feel like giving up and just putting this project manually in every application I make.

Comment: Both these files are in the same project though. So I cant add a reference to the class project.

Comment: Can you send me a example of what your doing ?

Comment: Hi, I didn't notice your original answer was editied with a download link - Thanks. Alright so here is my incomplete project (please ignore any bad coding habits) [Download Example](http://rintoul.eu/Files/ErrorHandle.zip) - As you can see both the form and the class file are in the same project.

Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: the method ErrorHandler is never called ?

Comment: its incomplete at the moment, stopped because I couldn't figure out how to use ErrorHandler, and Emailer on the form thats in the project.

Comment: are you looking for this ? ErrorWindow.ShowDialog()

Comment: Well, you see the sub (emailer) that I have in the Class file (in ErrorHandleMain.vb) I want that to be useable in the form (in frmErrorWindow.vb) so for instance, when the user clicks the submit button I want to be able to call emailer but for some reason it doesnt work.

In the form, I cant `ErrorHandleMain.Emailer(vars)` as I just get a warning saying "Reference to a non-shared member requires object reference" and intellisense only shows `equals`and `referenceequals` -- I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Before calling Errorhandlemain.emailed(vars) call dim errorhandler as new  ERRORHANDLEMAIN then call errorhandler.emailer(vars)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't too sure if that would work, I mean I know it allows me to access the Class, but as it was creating a new object. I'll give it a go _Thank you very much for all your help!_